# Django forms: How to add class to field_content?

Tags: django, django-forms

When I render a form, it generates something like this for each Field:

```
<div class="field_content">
    <label>...</label>
    <div class="field">...</class>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to uniquely identify each Field in my stylesheet. Is there a way to add another class to the outer div (in addition to field_content), or an outer div (parent to field_content)?

Answer (score 0):

If it's enough to set the class of the field you can specify it as [an attribute of your widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances):

```
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special'}))
```

If you need more control it's probably best to [render your form manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template) or if you don't mind relying on an external app there are even more flexible solutions:

In [django-floppyforms](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) you could use [`form layouts`](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html#using-form-layouts) and in [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org) you could use [`layout objects`](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/layouts.html#universal-layout-objects) and  to achieve what you want.

Comment: django-floppyforms (http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is an alternative package that gives you complete control over how forms render. I mention it because it's in the process of being integrated into Django core, so soon, this will just be how Django forms are done.

Comment: Ah, right. @Chris, do you have a link where one can find more information about the floppyforms integration into Django? So far i preferred crispy-forms due to it's nice integration with Twitter Bootstrap, though i really like the idea of having a more flexible form library as part of Django's Core.

Comment: floppyforms gives you the ability to customize every aspect of form generation, so it's trivial to make it work with any CSS framework. Since it literally uses templates, you can make it whatever you want it to be.

Comment: This adds the tag to the input control, not the outer div.

Comment: I updated my answer to make this more obvious. So yeah, if you really need the class on the outer div you should probably render the form manually or use one of the form apps.

@Chris
I took a closer look at floppyforms and it looks indeed very nice. I found [this comment](http://bruno.im/2012/jun/11/django-floppyforms-10-released/#c51) quite helpful to grasp the general (design) differences between crispy-forms and floppyforms.

Comment: That does explain the difference well, and I guess that's why I like floppyforms. I've always felt wrong using Python code to specify things like classes and other attributes on fields. That's the purview of the template, you just can't do it in the template in the current iteration of Django forms.